# SSL handshake requested, SSL feature not available in this build

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to run a android application, which uses node.js and mongodb for the server side. While trying to use the application, I get the following error:

> [conn16] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17133 SSL handshake requested, SSL feature not available in this build

What might be the problem?

Comment: MongoDB in itself is not SSL enabled, you need to build it with the SSL capability.Did you follow this? http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/administration/ssl/

Comment: @BatScream, no but I used curl with --insecure and got the same error. It doesn't seem to actually be related to SSL